# Debugging OpenOffice crashes

Tags: openoffice.org, debug

This is partly an OpenOffice question and partly a Ubuntu question. I'm running OpenOffice 3.2.0 and Ubuntu 10.04. I get frequent crashes of OO, especially the Calc app, although I get crashes in the word processor as well. They are very abrupt and accompanies by no warning or error message. I'm just typing away and then the app is gone. Sometimes I even end up thinking I'm typing in OO and discover that OO has crashed and I'm typing in whatever application was under OO. However, I can't reproduce these crashes on demand. They seem random. I can open the same file and do the same exact thing but it does not crash.

In Ubuntu how do I trace, track, or diagnose these types of crashes? Is there software I can invoke to help diagnose? Can I start OO from a command prompt with debugging of some sort enabled?

Note: if someone could add the tag OpenOffice, I would appreciate it

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProcedures) are the debugging procedures for Ubuntu. [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingOpenOffice) are the ones particular for OpenOffice. One of the first things to do, is to install the [dbg packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash), since they allow proper stack traces.